# VLC ":rate=2.0" - Where do I put this in command-line?

Tags: command-line, bash, vlc

I figured out a way to transcode my videos so that they would play at double speed using the GUI as "Convert/Stream" --> "Show More options" and adding `:rate=2.0` after `:file-caching=300` in the "Edit Options" box. Where exactly do I put this `:rate=2.0` when I am transcoding my video using command-line?

For eg:

```
vlc -vvv "my video.avi" :sout="#transcode{width=320,canvas-height=240,vcodec=mp4v, vb=768, acodec=mp4a, ab=96, channels=2}:std{access=file, mux=mp4, url=myvideo.mp4}" vlc:quit
```

Where do I put `:rate=2.0` ??

I am doing this so that I can use a bash script to batch-convert video lectures so that I can play them on my ipod at double speed.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
vlc --rate=2.00 -vvv "my video.avi" --sout .......
```

Comment: Didn't work. The following happened:
`code`

shikhar@shikhar-HP-Pavilion-dv2000:~$ vlc --rate-2.00 -vvv "/home/shikhar/Videos/psy.flv" :sout="#transcode{width=320,canvas-height=240,vcodec=mp4v, vb=768, acodec=mp4a, ab=96, channels=2}:std{access=file, mux=mp4, url=myvideo.mp4}" vlc:quit


vlc: unknown option or missing mandatory argument `--rate-2.00'
Try `vlc --help' for more information.